# CSS file is removed, but Visual Studio behaves like the file is still existing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I removed a CSS file from a folder in *Solution Explorer*, but *Visual Studio* behaves like the file is still existing.

How can I permanently erase a file in a *Visual Studio Solution* so that it's really gone for good?

Comment: Try Build > Clean Solution?

Comment: Maybe browser cache?

Comment: Visual Studio does, or the browser you are using does? Keep in mind that browsers usually cache CSS files. Usually doing a `CTRL+F5` will usually refresh them, depending on the browser.

Comment: It must be in cache of firefox, in order browse the problem not exist, i don't know how to clear cache in firefox

Comment: Perhaps they are still included in your .csproj? Did you delete the files through visual studio or from the explorer?

Comment: I tried to clarify the problem. The question should be easily answerable now, because the question asked is a quite common problem.

Answer (score 0):

Clean solution or delete your bin folder and build again.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted history on firefox and problem is gone, thanks Guys